# Is there any way to connect android and IOS devices programmatically via bluetooth in iOS/swift?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, connection, multipeer-connectivity

Currently i am using MultipeerConnectivity kit for making connection between iOS devices. But need is to detect or scan android devices too to connect with them.

Comment: write a simple socket program, advertise ur device using UDP protocol in network and list them and show in tableView/listView and then when user taps on specific device establish TCP connection that should do the job

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SandeepBhandari. Can you please share the demo with me if available.

Comment: Just an FYI on bluetooth PTP. Although the Apple docs haven't been updated, apparently Apple has dropped bluetooth support on the MultipeerConnectivity framework as of iOS 11. This is per an Apple staff member, Quinn "Eskimo" on the Apple forums. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92491 "...be aware that peer-to-peer Bluetooth support was removed in iOS 11...That leaves you with just peer-to-peer Wi-Fi."

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I have ptp bluetooth working solidly using MPC across iOS devices on iOS versions 12.1 and 12.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Multipeer Connectivity will only allow you to connect with other iOS devices.

It might be worth looking at the [Thali project](http://thaliproject.org/) which is a library built on top of Cordova to achieve what you're trying to do. If you look at their source code, you might be able to glean some information on how to do this yourself.